# How to write multiple lines to a text file in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, fs

Within a javascript function, I'm taking in a list of events and for each event, I would like to write text to a file. I have provided the correct

```
// Code within another function
events.map(event => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        const end = event.end.dateTime || event.end.date;
        outputMonthlySessions(`${event.summary}: ${start} - ${end} \n`);
      });
// Function to write to file called sessions located at FILE_PATH
function outputMonthlySessions(content) {
  fs.writeFile(SESSIONS_PATH, content, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  });
}
```

When I run the function containing that loop, I only get 1 event printed on the SESSIONS text file, but I should be printing 10. That tells me something is wrong with the loop or how I'm using writeFile. I suspect it's something to do with async but then not sure how to format my loop to make it work.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `forEach()` if you're not using the return value of `map()`.

Comment: Use `fs.writeFileSync()`

Comment: @Barmar if I'm using the object itself to write to the file how would I reference each individual object using the forEach() loop?

Comment: The same way you reference it inside `map()`. They both iterate over the array the same way. The difference is that `map()` also returns an array of all the function results.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) for `fs.writeFile()`:

> Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists.
> ...
> It is unsafe to use filehandle.writeFile() multiple times on the same file without waiting for the promise to be resolved (or rejected).

You are overwriting the file each iteration by calling `writeFile` every time, possibly before the promise is resolved. Instead, I think the simplest approach is to write your text to an intermediate object `data` (`<string> | <Buffer> | <TypedArray> | <DataView> | <Object>`) and then `filehandle.writeFile(data)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fsPromises.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesappendfilepath-data-options) to append to the file each time instead of overwriting it every time:

`./main.mjs`:

```js
import {appendFile, readFile} from 'fs/promises';

const SESSIONS_PATH = './sessions_data';

// Append to the file instead of overwriting the entire file
const outputMonthlySessions = (content) => appendFile(SESSIONS_PATH, content);

async function main () {
  const start = 'now';
  const end = 'later';

  const events = [
    {
      summary: 'first',
      start: { date: start },
      end: { dateTime: end },
    },
    {
      summary: 'second',
      start: { dateTime: start },
      end: { date: end },
    },
  ];

  for (const event of events) {
    const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
    const end = event.end.dateTime || event.end.date;
    await outputMonthlySessions(`${event.summary}: ${start} - ${end} \n`); /*
    ^^^^^
    Await the promise before continuing to the next loop iteration */
  }

  const text = await readFile(SESSIONS_PATH, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  console.log(text.split('\n'));
}

main();
```

In the terminal:

```
so-72718707 % node --version  
v16.15.1

so-72718707 % node main.mjs    
[ 'first: now - later ', 'second: now - later ', '' ]
```